# How to copy and paste a picture found on the web to wordpress easily

Tags: images, uploads

Anyone knows how to do so? What about if you want to edit the pics a little bit before pasting.

I am using windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should not be a lengthy process.

### Straight from the web:

1. **Right click** > `Copy image location`
2. WordPress: Add Media > `From URL`

### Editing a picture:

1. **Right click** > `Copy image`
2. Paste into your favorite photo editor (e.g. [GIMP](http://gimp.org/))
3. Edit and Save
4. WordPress: Add Media > `From Computer`

Note: with WordPress 3.3 you can also [drag-and-drop](http://wordpress.org/news/2011/12/sonny/) files.

Comment: +1 The drag and drop in WP3.3 is a great feature, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: +1. What happen is I copy the pics to microsoft picture manager. Well, I can't copy pics to clipboard once the pics are there.

Comment: Copy paste would be easier.

Comment: Compared to what you can do on this very site, these steps feel like something from 10 years ago.

Answer (score 3):

Marketplace is rather void of a plugin to enhance this workflow. My designer team wants to clip random parts of any page, which means copy as URL etc aren't going to do the job. I'm sort of surprised this isn't in the core yet.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-elevator/ seems to be the most trustworthy choice so far. Another plugin, Imagepaste, looks unmaintained.

Comment: **IMAGE ELEVATOR** rules !

Answer (score 1):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-clipboard/

> Support paste images from clipboard for posts & comments (based on filereader.js). For example,
>   you can take a screenshot using monosnap, and attach it to a post or comment using keyboard shortcuts CTRL+V.

I haven't tried this one yet, but I did try Image Elevator and found it broke pasting in Firefox using Ctrl+V.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another, quicker way to do this:

1. Copy the picture with Ctrl-C (keyboard) or Right-click|Copy (mouse)
2. To edit the picture first:

   - paste it into a simple photo editor (my favourite is PhotoFiltre; GIMP is too complicated for simple tasks like this). To paste an image, type Ctrl-Shift-V (keyboard) or in the menu click Edit|Paste as new image (mouse).
   - Edit the picture as desired. You do not need to save the image.
   - Copy the new edited image: Ctrl-A to select all and then Ctrl-C to copy (keyboard) or Select|Select all and then Edit|Copy (mouse).
   - In the edit post/page window in WordPress, paste the image directly in Visual view: Ctrl-V.

Two problems with this method:

1. It will not save the image to the media library. It is for quick-and-dirty image posting only.
2. The background HTML code for images pasted directly into WordPress is hideous. For cleaner HTML, install the Save Data:URL images plugin, which saves the image to
   your media folder (but still doesn't actually add it to the Media
   Library, as of version 0.1).

Answer (score 0):

Image Elevator as mentioned above. I use the premium version [($14 on Code Canyon)](https://codecanyon.net/item/image-elevator-for-wordpress/4311188)  on most websites I work on and it saves a ton of time. It will resize image dimensions and file sizes.

The [Embed Image Links plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/embed-image-links/) is also pretty handy if you are getting images via URL. Although it has not been tested with the latest version of WordPress.